# Make imported model fit screen in threejs

Tags: three.js, aframe

I do not want to change the camera to fit the model. I would prefer to know the correct dimensions given a location to make sure the model/geometry once scaled will be in the screen.

I don't want to move the camera since I might have many different objects.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to scale the model, with `scale="0.1 0.1 0.1"` or whatever. To do that automatically, consider writing a new component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('autoscale', {
  init: function () {
    var el = this.el;
    el.addEventListener('model-loaded', function (e) {
      var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(e.detail.model);
      var scale = 1 / (bbox.max.x - bbox.min.x);
      el.setAttribute('scale', {
        x: scale,
        y: scale,
        z: scale,
      });
    });
  }
});
```

To be more robust, you should probably use the largest dimension (x vs y vs z) for scaling, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: Cool Thanks. Will try tonight.

Answer (score 1):

This is my approach to it, and it work well for me. Assuming you already have mesh in your code.

```
 const box3 = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh);
 const size = new THREE.Vector3()
 box3.getSize(size)

 var scale = {
   x: 1 / (box3.max.x - box3.min.x),
   y: 1 / (box3.max.y - box3.min.y),
   z: 1 / (box3.max.z - box3.min.z)
 };

 mesh.scale.set(scale.x + mesh.scale.x, scale.y + mesh.scale.y, scale.z + mesh.scale.z)

 const centre = new THREE.Vector3()
 box3.getCenter(centre)
 mesh.position.set(mesh.position.x - centre.x, mesh.position.y - centre.y, mesh.position.z - centre.z)// = new THREE.Vector3(-centre.x, -centre.y, -centre.z)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer hopefully will help someone not using AFrame specifically.